# Report viewer in C# not view data Error viewing my RDLC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

i designed report and use table to view data if save data in database and use data set to return last row not view in report viewer but if return ((last row) -1) will view data in report ,
meaning the data inserted and retrieve data and the program running not view data but if inserted and stop run and run will view data >> how fix this problem,

```
this.selected_principle_material_for_preview_buy_menu_tableTableAdapter.
  execute_‌​fill_query(this.principle_dataset.
  selected_principle_material_for_preview_buy_men‌​u_table,buf_menu_id-1);
```

Other steps in design mode for create query and put data in table

Comment: could you provide us more sample code in order to get help ?

Comment: this.selected_principle_material_for_preview_buy_menu_tableTableAdapter.execute_fill_query(this.principle_dataset.selected_principle_material_for_preview_buy_menu_table,buf_menu_id-1);
       


other steps in design mode for create query and put data in table

Comment: I have incorporated your comment into your question.  I tried to edit the entire question; however, it is impossible (for me) to make sense of the first paragraph.  You may want to break it down into simpler sentences.

Answer (score 0):

i use report viewer to print report >>> 
if insert data and show data in report viewer not show , BUT
if insert data and stop program and re run program and show data in report viewer show .